# Can't Set Default in Twitter Bootstrap Toggleable Tab

Tags: javascript, tabs, twitter-bootstrap, nav

The tabs work nicely when clicked but selecting the default tab on window load fails. The javascript runs, no errors, but nothing happens. Any ideas?

```
<head>
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<script>
  //<![CDATA[
    window.onload=function () {
      $('#client_tab2').tab();
      };
  //]]>
</script>
<ul class='nav nav-tabs' id='tab'>
  <li><a href="#client_tab1" data-toggle="tab">General</a></li>
  <li><a href="#client_tab2" data-toggle="tab">Applications</a></li>
  <li><a href="#client_tab3" data-toggle="tab">Family</a></li>
  <li><a href="#client_tab4" data-toggle="tab">Memos</a></li>
</ul>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/clients/4512" class="simple_form client tab-content" id="edit_client_4512" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
  <div class='tab-pane active' id='client_tab1'>
  <legend>General Information</legend>
  </div>

  <div class='tab-pane' id='client_tab2'>
  <legend>Application Information</legend>
  </div>

  <div class='tab-pane' id='client_tab3'>
  <legend>Family</legend>
  </div>

  <div class='tab-pane' id='client_tab4'>
  <legend>Memos</legend>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, try it like this instead:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#tab a[href="#client_tab2"]').tab('show');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TjjKE/

Comment: Very nice! I couldn't use the $(window).load but window.onload with the rest of your tip works great! Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can also set a default tab as active by just `<li class="active"><a href="#whatever">....</a></li>` and then on the appropriate tab have `<div id="whatever" class="tab-pane active">..</div>` and eliminate the need for more JS. have a look at [this](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)