# bootstrap div with tabs auto display second tab at page load

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, html, bootstrap-tabs

I have a div with multiple tabs that display nested divs when you click on each tab. I need to know how I can display the second tab automatically at page load:

```
  <div style="border: solid 1px #ddd; padding: 6px 6px; min-height: 300px;">
                <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li><a href="#general" data-toggle="tab">General Info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#narrative" data-toggle="tab">Narrative</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#audit" data-toggle="tab">Audit</a></li>
               </ul>
                <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content paddingbottom20">
                    <div id="general" class="tab-pane">

                  </div>
                     <div id="narrative" class="tab-pane">

                    </div>
                    <div id="audit" class="tab-pane">

                    </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: This is bootstrap's tab plugin.

Comment: You should have mentioned bootstrap tabs plugin to help understand better.

Answer (score 5):

Use "active" class.

```
 <li class="active"><a href="#narrative" data-toggle="tab">Narrative</a></li>

 <div id="narrative" class="tab-pane active"></div>
```

Comment: For some reason, on page load it shows that the second tab is active, yet it displays the content of the first tab. I want to achieve the same thing (display second tab content on page load). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Bootstrap tabs, try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10304394/347455

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#tab a[href="#client_tab2"]').tab('show');
});
```

ETA: as other answer points out, "active" class also works